# Tmux - Tmux true color is not working properly

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'm using tmux for sometime now,

I use vim for coding, and I've noticed some flaws related to the colorschemes ONLY when I'm using vim with tmux.

Both terminal support 256 colors when I run this:  tput colors

When I test my terminal to see if support true colors this is the result:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnMorales/dotfiles/master/colors/24-bit-color.sh | bash
```

the output from the terminal is this:
[image]

but when I run this within tmux:
[image]

I've checked the result of echo $TERM but both of them return this:

```
xterm-256color
```

So I'm really confused about what might be the problem here =\

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me setting `alias tmux='tmux -2'` (in my .bashrc) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Perhaps you overlooked this in setting up (one can see that you overlooked **`Tc`**):

```
commit 427b8204268af5548d09b830e101c59daa095df9
Author: nicm <nicm>
Date:   Fri Jan 29 11:13:56 2016 +0000

    Support for RGB colour, using the extended cell mechanism to avoid
    wasting unnecessary space. The 'Tc' flag must be set in the external
    TERM entry (using terminal-overrides or a custom terminfo entry), if not
    tmux will map to the closest of the 256 or 16 colour palettes.

    Mostly from Suraj N Kurapati, based on a diff originally by someone else.
```

in tmux.conf:

```
# Enable RGB colour if running in xterm(1)
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"
```

in the manpage:

```
TERMINFO EXTENSIONS
     tmux understands some unofficial extensions to terminfo(5):
...
     Tc      Indicate that the terminal supports the ‘direct colour’ RGB
             escape sequence (for example, \e[38;2;255;255;255m).

             If supported, this is used for the OSC initialize colour escape 
             sequence (which may be enabled by adding the ‘initc’ and ‘ccc’  
             capabilities to the tmux terminfo(5) entry).
```

Regarding `-s` versus `-g`, the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) says:

> **`set-option`** [-agoqsuw] [-t target-session | target-window] option value
>                      (alias: set)
>   Set a window option with -w (equivalent to the
>   set-window-option command), a *server* option with **`-s`**, otherwise
>   a session option.  If **`-g`** is given, the *global session or window*
>   option is set.  The -u flag unsets an option, so a session
>   inherits the option from the global options (or with -g,
>   restores a global option to the default).
>
> The -o flag prevents setting an option that is already set and
>   the -q flag suppresses errors about unknown or ambiguous
>   options.
>
> With **`-a`**, and if the option expects a string or a style, value
>   is *appended* to the existing setting.

As I understand it,
Using `-s` means that new connections (created by the server) will get this setting, which is useful in shell initialization, while `-g` makes its changes too late for the shell initialization.

Further reading:

- [Add TrueColor Support #34](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/34)
- [Tmux true color support. #622](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/622)
- [Why only 16 (or 256) colors?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_16MegaColors) (ncurses FAQ)

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between `set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"` and `set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"` (which is what most blog posts seem to recommend) so far your sugested snippet `set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"` is the only thing that has worked for me.

Comment: The `-sa` instead of `-ga` was indeed the key factor to making true color work for me. Thank you!

Comment: Running the `set-option` command interactively (i.e. by <prefix> `:`, not by adding the command to tmux.conf), I found that it didn't take effect in my tty until I detached tmux and reattached.

Comment: @OtisWright `-s` is a Server option `-g` is a global session option (versus a non global session option that just affects the current session).  [This SO](https://superuser.com/questions/758843/difference-between-global-server-session-and-window-options) answer does a better job than I at explaining it.

Comment: It appears that now (tmux 3, maybe before) using the `RGB` option is preferred over the `Tc` tmux extension https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-rgb-colour.

Comment: The man page says `tmux understands some unofficial extensions to terminfo(5):` [source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) and lists `Tc`, but if you look at the `terminfo` manpage there is an RGB entry [source](https://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo). And a bit more on the topic: https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728

Comment: The terminfo manual page does not say that.   It uses "RGB" as a descriptive name, not as an *entry*.  The same applies to the tmux manual page.

Comment: Worth noting that you can find out the current terminal string (i.e. what is matched against the string that in the example is set to `xterm-*`) by running `echo $TERM` (*outside of a tmux session*). This is helpful if you're not sure what string your terminal sets.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `alacritty`, you can add the following to `.tmux.conf"`

```
set -g default-terminal "alacritty" 
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",alacritty*:Tc"
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo 'set -as terminal-overrides ",'"$(echo ${TERM%%-*})"'*:Tc"' >> ~/.tmux.conf
```

---

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-rgb-colour

> tmux must be told that the terminal outside supports RGB colour. This is done by specifying the `RGB` or `Tc` *terminfo(5)* flags. `RGB` is the official flag, `Tc` is a tmux extension.
>
> With tmux 3.2 and later this can be added with the `terminal-features` option:
>
> `set -as terminal-features ",gnome*:RGB"`
>
> Or for any tmux version the `terminal-overrides` option:
>
> `set -as terminal-overrides ",gnome*:Tc"`

and replace `gnome` with the result of `echo ${TERM%%-*}` (the first part of `$TERM` delimited by `-`) from the terminal emulator that you are currently using outside `tmux` such as `putty` or `xterm`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `WSL2` in the `Windows Terminal` and, only applying the above solutions didn't work for me.

**To fix it** had to go to `Settings`>`Rendering` and turn on the option `Use software Rendering`:

[image]

My terminal settings in tmux are:

```
set-option -sg default-terminal "screen-256color"
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:256"
```